# WPF Cascading Combobox using PRISM 6

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

To keep things simple, I  have two comboboxes on my view. I would like to cascade them while adhering to the MVVM design pattern and the PRISM 6 framework. Following Brian Lagunas MVVM/Prism [webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfBy2nfykqY) he mentions the `DelegateCommand`'s `ObservesProperty`. I have a hunch that's something I should be using but not sure. I provided a very simple View and ViewModel that I can't get working.

#### XAML (View):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PackageNames}" SelectedItem="{Binding PackageNameSelected}" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PackageOptions}"/>
```

#### ViewModel:

```
public MainWindowViewModel() // Constructor
{
    PackageNamesCommand = new DelegateCommand(PackageNamesCommandExecute);
    PackageOptionsCommand = new DelegateCommand(PackageOptionsCommandExecute).ObservesProperty(() => PackageNameSelected);
}

private string _packageNameSelected;
public string PackageNameSelected
{
    get { return _packageNameSelected; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _packageNameSelected, value); }
}

private ObservableCollection<string> _packeNames;
public ObservableCollection<string> PackageNames
{
    get { return _packeNames; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _packeNames, value); }
}

private ObservableCollection<string> _packageOptions;
public ObservableCollection<string> PackageOptions
{
    get { return _packageOptions; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _packageOptions, value); }
}

public DelegateCommand PackageNamesCommand { get; set; }

private async void PackageNamesCommandExecute()
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetPackageNames()).ContinueWith(t => PackageNames = ToObservableCollection(t.Result));
}

private IQueryable<string> GetPackageNames()
{
    return //My LINQ Query Here
}

public DelegateCommand PackageOptionsCommand { get; set; }

private void PackageOptionsCommandExecute()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetPackageOptions()).ContinueWith(t => PackageOptions = ToObservableCollection(t.Result));
}

private IQueryable<string> GetPackageOptions()
{
    return // My LINQ query here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a Prism issue.  To accomplish this task you simply need to place code in the setter of the PackageNameSelected property and then call your method to generate the dependent collection of options.  There are other ways to do it, but this is the most straight forward.